# Major trouble trying to verify and deploy Google Slides Add-on that will assign slides to students and combine them into one class presentation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

**Trouble with deploying Google Slides add-on.**

I am trying to publish a Google Slides Add-on named "Assign and Combine Google Slides" for teachers. The add-on requires teachers to have a list of student emails in column A of a Google Sheet and when they click the add-on in slides, it will assign each of those students a slide. Then, when students are done working in their own individual slides, the teacher goes back to the add-on and clicks on "merge slides" so that all the slides are combined into one class presentation. When I test it out in the apps script it works as intended. But when I try to go about getting it verified and published in the Google Cloud Console, I run into this issue when I try to enter the URL of the spreadsheet into the dialog box that pops up when assigning the slides. Here is the error message: **Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.** What am I doing wrong?

I have re-created this project several times in both the Google Apps Script and in the Google Cloud Console and keep getting this error. The weird thing is, if I just use the script without trying to tie it to the Google Cloud Console, it works just fine.